# TextBox text and xor filter

Tags: c#, text, xor

my problem today in C#.
I make xor crypt for my text lines, and want make for it generator, but my TextBox with source text return diffential string and result is not true.

Xor function:

```
private string GetText(byte[] Text)
{
    byte[] Key = { 0x12, 0x05, 0x52 };
    // ----
    for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
    {
        Text[i] ^= Key[i % 3];
    }
    // ----
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Text);
}
```

True result:

```
string Text = ".\\MyExample.txt";
textBox2.Text = GetText(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Text)); //Result: <Yk@*sh"~`|f}&
```

False result:

```
string Text = textBox1.Text; //Text: ".\\MyExample.txt"
textBox2.Text = GetText(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Text)); //Result: <Y_|jd?bi7<q*f
```

Why i get different results and how it fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains an escaped backslash.  C# is converting `\\` to a single `\`:

```
string Text = ".\\MyExample.txt";  // Text == ".\MyExample.txt"
```

If you want Text to contain `\\`, use one of the following methods:

```
string Text = @".\\MyExample.txt";
string Text = ".\\\\MyExample.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

The text you are defining in the first sample is not the same as the text coming from the TextBox.

```
string Text = ".\\MyExample.txt";
string TextBoxText = textBox1.Text; // is actually ".\\\\MyExample.txt"
```

The `\` is an escape character, thus if you were to display `".\\MyExample.txt"` in your TextBox, you would see `.\MyExample.txt`.